# Deformations of Hopf manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Recall that a Hopf manifold is a quotient $\mathbb C^n\setminus 0$ by a free action of $\mathbb Z$ where the generator is acting by a holomorphic contraction.

**Question 1.** Is it true that any deformation of a Hopf manifold (as a complex manifold) is again a Hopf manifold for $n\ge 3$?

**Question 2.** Is there some kind of classification of Hopf manifolds and their deformations in dimension $\ge 3$ (for example $n=3$).

Note that for $n=2$ the answer to both questions is positive  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_surface

Comment: Try this https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01076716

Comment: This paper by Haefliger should do it: http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1985__55_2_241_0

Answer (score 7):

Both questions are answered affirmatively for sufficiently small deformations in [this paper by Haefliger.](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1985__55_2_241_0)

Comment: YangMills, thanks a lot for both references! This leaves open just the question about all deformations (i.e. not small), as far as I understand?